# How to put JSON object into HyperLink rel attribute in ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I want to include JSON object into HyperLink rel attribute in ASP.NET page, to consume this object by javascript later. I am using code like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_MATERIALSAP" DataSourceID="dsMaterials">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSelector" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" rel='<%# ComposeJsonObject(Eval("ID_MATERIALSAP"), Eval("NAME")) %>' CssClass="selector" Text="Select"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Method `ComposeJsonObject` returns JSON object as string. I have problem that JSON contains double quote (") chars and binding single quotes (') are replaced with double quotes by ASP. So generated code is not valid and looks like this:

```
<a id="controlId" class="selector" rel="{"id":"300433460","title":"Material name"}" href="#">Select</a>
```

How can I just keep single quote quoted rel content to result like this:

```
<a id="controlId" class="selector" rel='{"id":"300433460","title":"Material name"}' href="#">Select</a>
```

Or is there other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution. JSON string can be url encoded. So I modified method ComposeJsonObject to return JSON encoded by `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`. Result is now this:

```
<a id="controlId" class="selector" rel="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;300433460&quot;,&quot;Material name&quot;:&quot;test&quot;}" href="#">Select</a>
```

and parsing json to object works fine. I am using `jQuery.parseJSON();` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rel attribute in the rowdatabound event of the GridView. Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_MATERIALSAP" DataSourceID="dsMaterials" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSelector" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" CssClass="selector" Text="Select"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Create an instance of the datarow
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        Hyperlink hlSelector = e.Row.FindControl("hlSelector") as HyperLink;
        hlSelector.Attributes.Add("rel", ComposeJsonObject(drv["ID_MATERIALSAP"].ToString(), drv["NAME"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution is nice and logic, but result is still the same.